# Dynamic ListView doesn't update OnPropertyChange in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I have a problem with ListView Update. I'm using dynamic TabControl in code behind in those Tabs ListViews are creating. Bindings are active unfortunatelly OnPropertyChanged doesn't update ListView.

Home.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class Home : UserControl
{
    private List<TabItem> _tabItems;
    private TabItem _tabAdd;
  
    public Home()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            _tabItems = new List<TabItem>();
            _tabAdd = new TabItem();
            _tabAdd.Header = "+";

            _tabItems.Add(_tabAdd);

            tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

            tabDynamic.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private TabItem AddTabItem()
    {

        int count = _tabItems.Count;

        TabItem tab = new TabItem();
        tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
        tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
        tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;

        var binding = new Binding("Tabs");
        binding.Source = tab;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(tab, TabItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);

        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.Name = string.Format("serviceRequests{0}",count);
        listView.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
        listView.ItemsSource = ((HomeViewModel)(this.DataContext)).ServiceRequests;
        listView.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        GridViewColumn gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        gridViewColumn.Header = "Temat";
        gridViewColumn.Width = 180;
        gridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Topic");

        scrollViewer.Content = grid;
        grid.Children.Add(listView);
        listView.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);

        tab.Content = scrollViewer;

        _tabItems.Insert(count - 1, tab);
        return tab;
    }
    private void tabDynamic_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tab = tabDynamic.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        if (tab == null) return;

        if (tab.Equals(_tabAdd))
        {
            // clear tab control binding
            tabDynamic.DataContext = null;

            TabItem newTab = this.AddTabItem();

            // bind tab control
            tabDynamic.DataContext = _tabItems;

            // select newly added tab item
            tabDynamic.SelectedItem = newTab;
        }
        else
        {
            // your code here...
        }
    }
```

HomeViewModel.cs

```
public class HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ILoggedUser loggedUser;
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest> _serviceRequests = new ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest>();

    public ICommand RequestCommand { get; }
    private readonly IRequestQueue _requestQueue;
    private readonly IQueueCreator _queueCreator;

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest> ServiceRequests 
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceRequests;
        }
        private set
        {
            _serviceRequests = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ServiceRequests));
        }
    }

    public HomeViewModel(ILoggedUser loggedUser, IRequestQueue requestQueue, IQueueCreator queueCreator)
    {
        ServiceRequests = new ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest>();
        this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
        _requestQueue = requestQueue;
        _queueCreator = queueCreator;

        RequestCommand = new RequestCommand(_requestQueue, _queueCreator, this);
    }

    public void SetRequests(List<ServiceRequest> requests)
    {
        ServiceRequests = new ObservableCollection<ServiceRequest>(requests);
    }
}
```

But if i do the same in .xaml it works fine (like below ex.)

```
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0, 0, 0 , 0">
                <Grid>
                    <ListView x:Name="serviceRequests" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceRequests}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

I'm newbie in Mvvm and wpf am i missing something? It seems like viewModel and codebehind have problem with listening each other.

Comment: It is unclear how your Home UserControl is supposed to be connected to a HoimeViewModel instance, or if that was even your intention. In general, it is a mistake that a UserControl sets its own DataContext. And why are UI elements created in code behind?

Comment: How can i create dynamic UI controls if not in code-behind? Code above is a dynamic new tab creation each tab contains listView. There is other way to create dynamic controls? If you ask about "Connection" i've meant Binding.

Comment: By [Data Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Also take a look at [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0), in particular [Binding to collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#binding-to-collections).